# Matching exact number of digits in a string

Tags: bash, grep, regular-expression

Given a string, how can I find out that it contains exactly 7 consecutive digits number?

Such as `1505082` or `1505082_CSE_322` but not `15050821` or `15050821_CSE_322`

I've tried

```
grep -Eq [0-9]{7} <<< "1505082"
```

which returns `0` but

```
grep -Eq [0-9]{7} <<< "15050821"`
```

also returns `0`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in (please quote the regex or it will be interpreted as a shell glob):

```
grep -Eq '[0-9]{7}' <<< "1505082"
```

grep is matching the 7 digits. You can see what is being matched by replacing the q with an `o`:

```
$ grep -Eo '[0-9]{7}' <<< "1505082"; echo "$?"
1505082
0
```

And yes, it will also match this:

```
$ grep -Eq '[0-9]{7}' <<< "150508299999"; echo "$?"
1505082
0
```

It removed all the nines.
The problem is that you are making a not-anchored match and it will match a 7 digit (**or more**) number.

You can **anchor** with:

```
$ grep -Eq '^[0-9]{7}$' <<< "15050829999"; echo "$?"
1
```

---

To match a 7 digit number **anywhere** and followed or preceded by non-digits you need a completely different anchor:

```
$ grep -oP '(?<=^|[^0-9])[0-9]{7}(?=[^0-9]|$)' <<< "1505082"; echo $?
1505082
0

$ grep -oP '(?<=^|[^0-9])[0-9]{7}(?=[^0-9]|$)' <<< "1505082_CSE_322"; echo $?
1505082
0

$ grep -oP '(?<=^|[^0-9])[0-9]{7}(?=[^0-9]|$)' <<< "1505082999_CSE_322"; echo $?
0
```

Those are lookahead matches, one is a look-back:

```
(?<=^|[^0-9])
```

That match either the start of the string (`^`) or a non-digit. The other is a lookahead:

```
(?=[^0-9]|$)
```

which match either a non-digit or the end of the string.

---

The only other alternative with simpler `Extended` regex is to extract any run of `7` (or more) digits and then confirm that it is exactly 7 digits:

```
$ echo "150508299_CSE_322" | 
          grep -oE '[0-9]{7,}' | 
                  grep -qE '^[0-9]{7}$'; echo "$?"
1
```

Comment: Could you tell me why ``grep -oP '(?<=^|[^0-9])[0-9]{7}(?=[^0-9]|$)' <<< "1505082_CSE_322" | wc -m`` is giving the output ``8``, shouldn't it give ``7`` as output?

Comment: For the same reason that `echo | wc -m` gives you `1`, it counts the newline character. Try `printf '\n\n\t\t' | wc -m` for example. @Robur_131

Answer (score 0):

When things get complicated with `grep`, you can always use `egrep` or even a programming language available in a linux/unix system to help you with your matches/regexp.

If your system has perl or ruby you can do it in one line:

`echo 1234567| ruby -lne 'print if /^\d{7}$/'`

`echo 1234567| perl -lne 'print if /^\d{7}$/'`

or

`cat file.txt | ruby -lne 'print if /^\d{7}$/'`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Bash's binary operator `=~` ?

```
$ [[ 1505082 =~ [0-9]{7} ]] && echo matched
matched
```

For details see: http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs

Comment: This would falsely match `15050821`, for example.